# Matlab-compiler: update data into a figure window

Tags: c++, matlab, matlab-deployment, matlab-compiler

Here is my problem:
I have an application in C++ and I use Matlab to visualize my results.

The code matlab is :

```
function y = plotArray(A)
plot(A)
end
```

I have create the library with mcc.
My data change with the time and want to update the plot and not close the windows and open a new one.

I've looked at the linkdata function available in matlab, but it is unsupported in the matlab complier.

Do you have any ideas? 
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would the clf command do what you want?

```
function y = plotArray(A)
clf %this clear the previous figure, without opening a new one
plot(A)
end
```